# Is a third-order tensor linear in both arguments?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ be smooth and for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ let $H_x(\cdot, \cdot)$ denote the Hessian third-order tensor of $f$. Basically given any two vectors $v, w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ it returns a third vector
$$
H_x(v, w)\in\mathbb{R}^m.
$$

> Is this third-order tensor linear in both arguments? That is
> $$
> H_x(a v_1 + b v_2, cw_1 + d w_2) = acH_x(v_1, w_1) + adH_x(v_1, w_2) + bcH_x(v_2, w_1) + bdH_x(v_2, w_2)
> $$
> for any four constants $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and four vectors $v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2 \in\mathbb{R}^n$?

#### Bonus

Also, given n $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is it also linear in the sense that $H_x(Av, w) = AH_x(v, w)$?

Comment: $H^k{}_{ij}(f)=\nabla_i\nabla_jf^k$. The Hessian is given by a composition of linear operators hence is linear.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks for the comment, what does the index $k$ represent here?

Comment: The $k$th component of $f$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Of course, thanks. I understand that in principle differential operators are linear, but with the third-order tensor I struggle to figure out what it means practically. I am familiar with linearity in terms of a function:
$$
f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)
$$
but here I am not sure if the linearity condition means what I have written above or not. Also, not sure what happens when the input is multiplied by a matrix, since we are working with order-three tensors? Does a matrix behave almost like a constant?

Comment: @K.defaoite I guess I struggle to understand if I can do the following operations:
$$
H_x(v_1 + v_2, w) = H_x(v_1, w) + H_x(v_2, w)
$$
$$
H_x(av, bw) = ab H_x(v, w)
$$
and finally what happens when I multiply by a matrix?
$$
H_x(Av, w) \overset{?}{=}
$$

Comment: @K.defaoite When $m=1$ then $H_x$ is a Hessian matrix and therefore we have a simple 
quadratic form
$$
H_x(v, w)= v^\top H_x w
$$
and then it's easy to see its linearity. Also, when $m=1$ if one of the inputs is multiplied by a matrix, this matrix simply multiplies the original one
$$
(Av)^\top H_x w = v^\top A^\top H_x w
$$
but it's not clear to me what the equivalent would be here when $m > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of competing terminology here. The Hessian operator $H$ is a linear map between functions, as per my comment. But the Hessian of $f$ is also a linear map on vectors (a tensor!). I understand now that that is what you are asking about.

---

A $(p,q)$ tensor is **defined** as a linear map $T:{\mathcal V^*}^p\times\mathcal V^q\to\mathbb R$. So linearity actually follows immediately from that. But I will illustrate.

Let's call the Hessian of $f$, $Hf$. As I said before,
$$(Hf)^k{}_{ij}=\nabla_i\nabla_j f^k$$
For generic vectors $u,v$,
$$\big((Hf)(u,v)\big)^k=(Hf)^{k}{}_{ij}u^iv^j$$
Which is clearly linear. Also

$$\big((Hf)(Au,v)\big)^k=(Hf)^k{}_{ij}(Au)^iv^j \\ =(Hf)^k{}_{ij}A^i{}_lu^lv^j$$
Which is, again, clearly linear.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I am not very familiar with index notation, so I will need some time to digest that. That should also mean that the Hessian is symmetric, right? But here I struggle to figure out what it means. 

When the Hessian is a matrix symmetry just means $H_x^\top = H_x$, that is it is equal to its transpose. Can we say the same here?

Comment: @Euler_Salter The Hessian is symmetric as long as your underlying space is flat :) which $\Bbb R^n$ is.

Comment: Symmetric I guess we are taking to mean $(Hf)^k{}_{ij}=(Hf)^k{}_{ji}$. This boils down to the fact that $\nabla_i\nabla_j=\nabla_j\nabla_i$ in flat space.

Comment: I understand your index notation, but I am struggling to figure out which side the matrix would come out from. For instance, if we have $H(Au, v)$ does it come out on the left or on the right? Left would be 
$$
H(Au, v) = AH(u, v)
$$
right would be
$$
H(Au, v) = H(u, v) A
$$

Comment: We are contacting on the lower index, so the left.

Comment: But then how is the multiplication still valid? Because $H(u, v)$ is meant to be an $m\times 1$ vector, whereas $A$ is going to be an $n\times n$ matrix.